# Excel: How to get total number of times substring occurs in a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cumulative-sum

I have an excel document, and I want to be able to total the amount of times a substring (A name) occurs in that range. This is a picture of a table that I would want to use this formula on. [image]

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Countif with wildcards.  It will look at the substring:

```
=COUNTIF($B:$D,"*" & G5 & "*")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you that was very quick and exactly what I needed.